# Do Genasi tolerate low temperatures better than humans?

Tags: dnd-5e, races

one of my D&D players just created the new character - The Fire Genasi Warrior. Our story probably will be placed in the Icewind Dale. I'm new in the D&D and you know - still learning and getting new things. My questions are:

***Do Genasi tolerate low temperatures better than humans? And does their body give off any heat?***

Comment: While at first blush it might make sense to say "She has fire in her, the cold doesn't effect her" it's probably more accurate to say "She likes and is adapted to heat, she probably doesn't like cold". Like a Jamaican bobsled team. Sounds fun to roleplay!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Fire Genasi do not *really* tolerate low temperatures better than humans, and while they are "feverishly hot" it is not a game mechanic like an Azer's Heated Body feature. However Fire Genasi *are* able to cast the Produce Flame cantrip at will, and the Burning Hands spell once per long rest.**

______________________________________________________________--

Fire Genasi do not have resistance (let alone immunity) to cold damage, so they are the same as humans in that regard. Resistance means the creature takes half damage from cold damage, and immunity means the creature would take no damage from cold damage (barring very special circumstances/spells that could negate such resistance or immunity).

However, all Genasi including Fire Genasi *do* get a +2 bonus that either goes to Constitution automatically or can be applied to Constitution if using Tasha's Cauldron of Everything ("TCoE") optional rules in Chapter 1 of that rule book.

The benefit of a higher constitution score is laid out in Dungeons Master's Guide ("DMG") pg110:

> EXTREME COLD: Whenever the temperature is at or below 0 degrees
> Fahrenheit, a creature exposed to the cold must succeed on a DC 10
> Constitution saving throw at the end of each hour or gain one level of
> exhaustion. Creatures with resistance or immunity to cold damage
> automatically succeed on the saving throw, as do creatures wearing
> cold weather gear (thick coats, gloves, and the like) and creatures
> naturally adapted to cold climates.

(The rules regarding Exhaustion can be found in the Player's Handbook ("PHB") on pg 291 where it details the effects of exhaustion, which can be quite serious up to and including death.)

Accordingly, depending on how much you put towards your Fire Genasi's Constitution score, it could make a little difference if for some reason you were caught in the cold without proper clothing.

As an aside, the Goliath player character race found in Volo's Guide to Monsters ("VGtM") rule book was always adapted to cold climates so it would always succeed on its saving throws vs extreme cold, and it has further been updated (in what is called an errata) that now gives the Goliath resistance to cold damage, a very substantial benefit.

Even further aside, Xanathar's Guide to Everything ("XGtE") rule book includes a racial feat available only to Tieflings called Infernal Constitution which among other things gives resistance to cold damage.

---

As to the body giving off heat, Fire Genasi are only feverishly hot, unlike an Azer's Heated Body feature, described in Monster Manual ("MM" rule book) pg 22 which states:

> Heated Body: A creature that touches an Azer or hits it with a melee
> attack while within 5 feet of it takes 5 (1d10) damage.

Accordingly, a Fire Genasis being "feverishly hot" is good for flavor, but there is no game mechanic advantage say compared to a human.

---

Finally, Fire Genasi do have the Reach to the Blaze racial feat, allowing them to cast the Produce Flame cantrip at will, and the Burning Hands spell once per long rest.

The Produce Flame cantrip does not appear to aid with cold damage or exhaustion from exposure to cold. Rather it provide illumination and can cause damage to other creatures.

On the other hand, the Burning Hands spell outlined in PHB pg 220 includes the following in its description:

> The fire ignites any flammable objects in the area that aren't being
> worn or carried.

Accordingly, this could help start a fire in the event you are caught out in the cold without proper clothing, and have access to fuel for a fire. However, a Tinderbox which costs 5 SP and weighs 1 pound would likely accomplish the same thing (refer to PHB pg 153).

Answer (score 1):

Genasi

> Nearly all fire genasi are feverishly hot as if burning inside, an impression reinforced by flaming red, coal- black, or ash-gray skin tones. The more human-looking have fiery red hair that writhes under extreme emotion, while more exotic specimens sport actual flames dancing on their heads. Fire genasi voices might sound like crackling flames, and their eyes flare when angered. Some are accompanied by the faint scent of brimstone.

Extreme Cold

> Whenever the temperature is at or below 0 degrees Fahrenheit, a creature exposed to the cold must succeed on a DC 10 Constitution saving throw at the end of each hour or gain one level of exhaustion. Creatures with resistance or immunity to cold damage automatically succeed on the saving throw, as do creatures wearing cold weather gear (thick coats, gloves, and the like) and creatures naturally adapted to cold climates.

They do not naturally have any specific cold resistance or immunity, they do give off a bit of heat (feverishly hot, possible actual fire on head). One could easily argue that their produce flame ability could be used to keep themselves warm (It harms neither you nor your equipment, but does not say it doesn't produce heat, such as the spell Continual Flame.)

If running Rime of the Frost Maiden, the book suggests granting new characters cold weather gear for free.

> All characters begin the adventure with a free set of cold weather clothing in addition to the starting equipment they receive from their class and background choices.